# Documentsディレクトリにあるdefault.realmについて

Tags: swift, realm

現在アプリに、普段はローカル（Realm）に保存されているデータをDropboxでバックアップできる機能をつけようと思っています。アップロードするためにはまずはドキュメントフォルダにある`default.realm`へのアクセスが必要かと思い、以下のコードを記述しているのですがエラーが発生します。どうすればエラーが出ずに、`default.realm`の情報が取得できるか教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true ).first {
    let path_file_name = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file_name)

    print(dir)
    print(path_file_name)

    do {
        let uplorddata = try NSString( contentsOfFile: path_file_name, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
        print(uplorddata)
    } catch {
        //エラー処理
        print("エラー")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmのファイルはテキストファイルではないので、`NSString(contentsOfFile:encoding:)`で読むことはできません。

[Dropboxのドキュメント](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#documentation)によると、ファイルのアップロードは下記のように、NSDataを`upload(path:input:)`メソッドの`input`パラメータに渡せばいいようなので、NSDataとして読む必要があると思います。

```
// Upload a file
let fileData = "Hello!".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
client.files.upload(path: "/hello.txt", input: fileData!).response { response, error in
...
```

指定したファイルパスのファイルをNSDataとして読み込むには、例えば`NSData(contentsOfFile:options:)`を使って下記のようにします。

```
do {
    let uplorddata = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path_file_name, options: [])
```

また、デフォルトのRealmの保存先は`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL`で取得できますので、パスを組み立てる必要はありません。

`try〜catch`ではエラーオブジェクトを取得するようにしたほうが何でエラーになったのかがわかって便利です。

ここまでをまとめると、下記のように修正できます。

```
if let realmFileURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL {
    print(realmFileURL)
    do {
        let uplorddata = try NSData(contentsOfURL: realmFileURL, options: [])
        print(uplorddata)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```